# $T_0$ is MVUE for $\gamma(\theta)$ and $T_1$ is an u.e. for $\gamma(\theta)$ with efficiency 0.0169. Then corr($T_0,T_1$ )?

Tags: correlation, estimation, point-estimation

The estimator $T_0$ is MVUE for $\gamma(\theta)$ and  $T_1$ is any other unbiased estimator for $\gamma(\theta)$ with efficiency 0.0169. Then what is the correlation coefficient between $T_0$ and $T_1$ ?

Comment: See our policy on [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple one-line proof if you know that a [necessary and sufficient condition](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-31.pdf) for an unbiased estimator to be UMVUE is that it must be uncorrelated with every unbiased estimator of zero.

Note that $T_1-T_0$ is an unbiased estimator of zero.

So you have $$\operatorname{Cov}_{\theta}(T_0,T_1-T_0)=0\quad\forall\,\theta\in\Theta$$

Use this to arrive at a simple expression for $\operatorname{Corr}_{\theta}(T_0,T_1)$ in terms of the efficiency of $T_1$.